# Http hosted silverlight applicaton crossdomain access https hosted service

Tags: silverlight, http, https, cross-domain

I am trying to make a call to rest service using web client (or webRequest.Create, results are same).

The Silverlight application is being developed on my maching with url localhost:13451

Rest service is hosted using https://contoso.com/Services/Service.csv

and a method to get list of entities has url structure defined as follows:

https://contoso.com/Services/Service.csv/username@password/?StartDate=10-11-2012

the crossdomain.xml file for https://contoso.com/ is accessible by https://contoso.com/crossdomain.xml

and contains such content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

So when I trying to make a request, Silverlight throws a security exception without specifying what is wrong. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Ignoring your specific error at the moment, you should only use the newer `clientaccesspolicy.xml` file type and never the old `crossdomain.xml` (which is only allowed for compatibility with old Flash sites that have that file already). `clientaccesspolicy.xml` has a lot more options/features.

Comment: What if you make crossdomain.xml accessible via http, not https?

Comment: I have had similar issues and it seems that additional configuration is required to talk to an https service than merely pointing silverlight at a https URL. You need to use the correct settings in the client used to connect within Silverlight. I have not tracked this down yet.

Answer (score 0):

When You need to add SL service references to service, put this on root of Your site:
clientaccesspolicy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*"  http-methods="*" >
        <domain uri="http://*"/>
        <domain uri="https://*"/> 
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

and crossdomain.xml containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

and make sure it is accesible over http or https via browser!
HTH